# Middleware order with expresss

Tags: node.js, express

I configured Express middleware as:

```
var clientDir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(clientDir));
app.use('/js', express.static(clientDir + '/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(clientDir + '/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(clientDir + '/partials'));
app.use('/lib', express.static(clientDir + '/lib'));
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    console.log("/*");
    res.sendfile('index.html', {
        root : clientDir
    });
});
```

When I request `/lib/require.js`, the content of index.html is served. To my understanding the request should be handled by `app.use('/lib', express.static(clientDir + '/lib'));`

Basically I want my routes to be handled first, then the static content and finally if the request is neither a route, neither a static content, the server should serve `index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding your statements:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(clientDir + '/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(clientDir + '/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(clientDir + '/partials'));
app.use('/lib', express.static(clientDir + '/lib'));
```

are meant to serve static content which is what your `app.use(express.static(clientDir))` will do anyways.

I'm guessing you confused `app.use('/lib', ...)` for `app.get()`, `app.post()` etc.

The latter are statements that construct `app.router` which is what you expected to handle your request for `lib/require.js`.

The former refers to "mounting" and does not affect the `app.router`. Mounting is telling Express that when a request for `/lib` arrives, it should be handled by `express.static(clientDir + '/lib')` and the handler receives the request with the `/lib` prefix stripped off. In your case, given that you obviously have  the file `clientDir + '/lib/require.js'` in your system, you expected it to be served but the problem is that the `app.use('/lib', express.static(clientDir + '/lib'))` statement is in reality just another middleware statement that comes after the:

```
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(clientDir));
```

and actually the only thing that is in your `app.router` is the `app.all('/*',...)` which explains why, no matter what you ask for, the `index.html` will always be served.

To solve your problem, just remove the block:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(clientDir + '/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(clientDir + '/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(clientDir + '/partials'));
app.use('/lib', express.static(clientDir + '/lib'));
```

which will all be handled by the `express.static` middleware and if you want the `index.html` to be served for everything else, maintain your `app.all()` but reverse the order of the first two middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(clientDir));
app.use(app.router);
```

This way all static files that exist, will be served and if not a static file, then the app router will kick in with the generic `app.all` route to server `index.html` as default.

For more on mounting, see [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).